# Problem with LFE channel in mixing

Tags: pro-tools, sound, film-sound-design, film-mixing, lfe

I have question about 5.1 . Is this right that we shouldnt have any soundeffects on LFE channel and all the sound effects Need to be sent to that channel?(in protools)

Comment: Welcome to sound.SE! This question is a bit flat – if technique _X_ can be done at all, then there will usually some particular situation where it is in fact useful (even if they're rare). A better question would be, what can be done with sounds on an LFE channel, and what are _problems_ that make this (perhaps usually!) a bad deal. — For another thing: “sound effect” is a bit of an ambiguous term. I suppose you mean a _sound event_ that's inserted as an effect into a film, but in other branches of sound production, “soundeffect” would rather be interpreted as “FX plugin”.

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) use the LFE send on whatever panner they are using for ProTools.  Either the built in panner, waves, spanner etc all have a LFE send that allows you to send the amount you want to the LFE.  If you only wanted a signal sent to the LFE then you could assign it to the LFE using a sub buss but depending on how and if your encoding your final mix the LFE channel could be dropped.